# Conditionally add data to Excel cell based on row value changing

Tags: excel, powerquery

I my trying to create an Excel (or PowerQuery) formula (or query) that will iterate through table like the below...

| Number | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Jim |
| 2 | Bella |
| 2 | Kate |
| 3 | Joe |
| 4 | Jake |
| 5 | Janet |
| 5 | Bee |

and create a table like the below in which the items with the same number are added to the same row and the items with a different number listed on separate rows.

| Number | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Jim Bella Kate |
| 3 | Joe |
| 4 | Jake |
| 5 | Janet Bee |

I've been able to solve this problem when the number changes on every row in Excel rather easily, but am at a loss as to how to do so when the number does not change. I'd sure appreciate some guidance.